# How to properly import JavaFX library?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using IntellIJ and just created a JavaFX sample project. I have not done any changes to the code but I am getting this Error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

my project.iml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library">
      <library name="javafx-fxml">
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/16/javafx-fxml-16.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/16/javafx-fxml-16-win.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/16/javafx-controls-16.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/16/javafx-controls-16-win.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/16/javafx-graphics-16.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/16/javafx-graphics-16-win.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-base/16/javafx-base-16.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/openjfx/javafx-base/16/javafx-base-16-win.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

Why doesn't the library in project.iml work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download JavaFX SDK and connect it to the project as a library. See the detailed guide in JetBrains [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html)
and pay attention to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#add-javafx-lib) section

And don't forget to define these libraries in VM options of a run configuration in use. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#vm-options)